# $1+2^x+\ldots+n^x \mid 1+2^y+\ldots+n^y$ for all $n$ implies $x=y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, perfect-powers

The following problem was proposed by A. Schinzel a couple of days ago at the 22nd Conference on Number Theory, held in Liptovsky Jan (Slovakia). He pointed out that the question has an affirmative answer in the case $x \le 3$, but nothing else in the remaining cases:

**Question:** Let $x$ and $y$ be *integers greater than $3$* for which, whenever $n$ is a positive integer, it holds
$$
1+2^x+\ldots+n^x \,\,\mathrm{ divides }\,\, 1+2^y+\ldots+n^y.
$$
Does it follow that $x=y$?

Comment: The affirmative answer is probably for $x \geqslant 3$, since for $x = 1$ and $y = 3$, we have the divisibility.

Comment: So, this seems to be an open question. What kind of answer do you expect here?

Comment: Oh, you are correct. I edited the question, thanks Daniel [he also didn't mention the trivial answer..]

Comment: @lhf Is it a known conjecture?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, I didn't know about it till now but if it has been posed at a Conference on Number Theory, it's probably an open problem

Comment: In fact, we all proposed problems we would like to have an answer; but it "doesn't" imply that it is impossible to give an answer, whatever this may mean.. Or better, "shouldn't", otherwise I am missing the meaning of the final problem section

Comment: lhf's question still remains: What is your exact question, if someone here can prove it for $x, y>3$?

Comment: In a word, yes; or, at least, if it can be shown in some cases, as it happened, just to cite one, for the Catalan conjecture

Comment: Looking at $n = 2$ gives us $y = (2k+1)\cdot x$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Correct, hence it is enough to assume that $x$ divides $y$ (and their ratio is odd)

Comment: If Schinzel couldn't answer it, it's likely to be a very hard problem.